# Eval'ing with s///e

Tags: regex, perl, eval, substitution

I'm learning Perl and get stuck on evaling in s/// operator.
I try to change 'hello world' to 'world, hello' and 'Hello world' to 'World, hello', i.e. preserve first titlecase letter if any in string even after changing words placement using s/// with /e or /ee option. This is my code

```
my @strs = (
    "hello world",
    "Hello world",
    );
foreach (@strs) {
    say 'ORIG: ', $_;
    s< (hello) \h+ (world) >
     < $_ = (( $1 =~ m[^\p{Lu}] ) ? qq[\u$2, \l$1] : qq[$2, $1]) >xie;
    say 'EDIT: ', $_ . "\n";
}
```

if I change for example

```
s< (hello) \h+ (world) >
 < $_ = (( $1 =~ m[^\p{Lu}] ) ? qq[\u$2, \l$1] : qq[$2, $1]) >xie;
```

to

```
s< (hello) \h+ (world) >
 < $_ = (( $1 eq 'Hello' ) ? qq[\u$2, \l$1] : qq[$2, $1]) >xie;
```

it works as needed but with m// it produces next output:

```
ORIG: hello world
EDIT: world, hello

ORIG: Hello world
Use of uninitialized value $2 in concatenation (.) or string at ./pl line 340, <> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $1 in lcfirst at ./pl line 340, <> line 2.
EDIT: ,
```

Where is the issue?

Comment: `(hello)` does not match "Hello" (upper case "H"). You could use `([Hh]ello)` instead. Also, you do not need to compare $1 with 'Hello' or anything either.

Comment: 1) I tried ([Hh]ello) - same result. Notice that I'm using /xie options in the end of s///, i.e. case-insensitive match is on.
2) How I can do conditional titlecase letter changing without condition in this case?

Comment: The facility for alternative delimiters for pattern matching and double-quote interpolation is intended to allow you to write more readable code. Using non-standard quote characters when they aren't called for makes your code *less* readable. Use the normal syntax where possible, like this `s{ (hello) \h+ (world) }{ $1 =~ /^\p{Lu}/ ? "\u$2, \l$1" : "$2, $1" }xie`. Note also that you don't need to assign to `$_` within the substitution.

Comment: Sorry Nikita, I misread your code. At first glance, your issues seemed to originate from not matching (hence $1 is undefined), but I should have given it a closer look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're losing the original values of `$1` and `$2` when you do the regular expression match `m//`. You could get around this by storing them to a temporary variables:

```
s< (hello) \h+ (world) >
 < my ($h,$w)=($1,$2); $_ = (( $1 =~ m[^\p{Lu}] ) ? qq[\u$w, \l$h] : qq[$w, $h]) >xie;
```

Actually, I don't think that you need to be using the `e` modifier at all. Your substitution could just be `s/([Hh]ello) ([Ww]orld)/$2, \L$1/`. This uses capture groups to swap the order of the words around and `\L` to make the first captured group ("hello") lowercase:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my @strs = ('hello world', 'Hello World');
map { s/([Hh]ello) ([Ww]orld)/$2, \L$1/; say } @strs;
```

If you specifically *want* to use `e`, you could use something like:

```
s/([Hh]ello) ([Ww]orld)/qq{$2, } . lc($1)/e
```

Output (using either approach):

```
world, hello
World, hello
```

Comment: It's almost but not that I want. I want to get exactly this:
    world, hello
    World, hello <--- notice lowercase 'h'

and yeah, I'm learning how to use different operators and it's s///e for now.

Comment: I've added an example using the `e` modifier which produces the output you want.

Comment: s/(hello) (world)/qq{$2, } . lc($1)/ie for 'Hello, world' returns 'world, hello' contrary to expected 'World, hello'(notice titlecase 'W'). With map it works as needed. The really question for me is why my example from main question doesn't work. I found workaround that I mentioned below the code... but what about m//? Why it doesn't work? Or even magically undefine $1 and $2(see warnings ibidem).

Comment: You are losing the values of `$1` and `$2` when you do the second match. I've updated my answer to explain. I've also changed my second example so that it uses `[Hh]` and `[Ww]` rather than doing case insensitive matching.